# QTreeWidget select first row

Tags: c++, qt

I've seen the solution for python, but I need to know how to do it outside of python.

Here is what I have:

```
myTree->setCurrentIndex(myTree->currentIndex().sibling(0,0));
```

I also understand that setCurrentItem is a good way to go, but I can't get that to work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `myTree->topLevelItem(0)` **does not** return `nullptr`, you can use the following:

```
myTree->setCurrentItem(
    myTree->topLevelItem(0),    // item
    0,                          // column
    QItemSelectionModel::Select // command
);
```

See Qt's [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#setCurrentItem-2).

Comment: Thank you, that is working.  

I am having a hard time using the documentation for QT. As someone who is learning, I see the information, and understand it, but there are so few examples on how to implement it that I'm simply struggling to put it all together.

Thanks for your help, I'm getting there.